# What implies "conditional heteroskedasticity" in (G)ARCH?

Tags: volatility, garch

I have trouble to understand what implies "conditional heteroskedasticity" term in (G)ARCH models. The residual $\epsilon$ is stationary, hence homoskedastic (unconditional variance is constant). Then, if we assume that residual has (G)ARCH structure, do we assume that it becomes heteroskedastic when it is conditioned w.r.t. its lags?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Cross Validated.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you have to differ between conditional and unconditional moments. If you look at nearly every time series of returns, you observe 2 things:

1. There is usually no doubt that the time series is stationary. Therefore, the unconditional variance $\text{Var}(r_t)$ must be constant and finite.
2. You observe volatility clustering, i.e., periods of high volatility tend to be followed by periods of high volatility and vice versa. In other words, it seems like the conditional variance $\text{Var}(r_t \vert \Omega_{t-1})$ is not constant, but changes over time.

Note that even if $\text{Var}(r_t \vert \Omega_{t-1})$ changes over time, $\text{Var}(r_t)$ can be constant. There is no contradiction between those two things. GARCH models simply try to mimic those stylized facts.

Let's take a look at the GARCH(1,1) model. This model assumes that the returns can be modeled as:
\begin{align}
r_t&=\mu_t+\epsilon_t, \quad \epsilon_t\vert \Omega_{t-1}\sim WN(0,\sigma_t^2),\\
\epsilon_t&=\sigma_tu_t \quad u_t \overset{iid}{\sim}(0,1),\\
\sigma_t^2&=\alpha_0+\alpha_1\epsilon_{t-1}^2+\beta_1\sigma_{t-1}^2.
\end{align}

Easy calculations show that in this model:
$$
\text{Var}(r_t\vert\Omega_{t-1})=E((r_t-\mu_t)^2\vert \Omega_{t-1})=E(\epsilon_t^2\vert \Omega_{t-1})=\sigma_t^2
$$
Therefore:
$$
\text{Var}(r_t \vert \Omega_{t-1})=E(\epsilon_t^2 \vert \Omega_{t-1})=\sigma_t^2=\alpha_0+\alpha_1\epsilon_{t-1}^2+\beta_1\sigma_{t-1}^2.
$$
The **conditional** variance is **not constant**. On the other hand, you can express the squared error terms as an ARMA(1,1) process
$$
\epsilon_{t}^2=\alpha_0+(\alpha_1+\beta_1)\epsilon_{t-1}^2+w_t-\beta_1w_{t-1}
$$
from which you can derive the **unconditional** variance
$$
\text{Var}(\epsilon_t)=E(\epsilon_t^2)=\frac{\alpha_0}{1-(\alpha_1+\beta_1)}
$$
which is **constant** and finite if $\alpha_1+\beta_1<1$. This explains the name of the model "Generalized **Conditional** heteroskedasticity".